# Regular expression to find an upper case and lower case letter in password for Android

Tags: regex, android-activity

I need a regular expression to validate a password. The criteria is that the password should contain at least one upper case and one lower case letter. I want to use it with a pattern matcher in Android.

Here is my attempt:

```
public static final String PWD_PATTERN_ALP_UP = "(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*"; 
public static boolean isAlphabetPresent(String text) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
        Constants.PWD_PATTERN_ALP_UP,
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text); 
    return matcher.find();
}
```

Comment: Did you make any effort in writing this?

Comment: Please show what you attempted. If you haven't attempted something yet, do that first, then post it. If you don't know where to start, read a basic tutorial on regex.

Comment: I have used [A-Za-z]. But it didnt work. Code written is       public static boolean isAlphabetPresent(String text) {
  
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Constants.PWD_PATTERN_ALP_UP, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
  return matcher.find();

Answer (score 1):

Please try this:

```
(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*
```

Comment: It didnt work. pattern matcher find return true for just a single character. I need to check the presense of both uppercase and lowercase letter

Comment: It works in the link provided. But I tried it in my android code. it didnt work. Code is given below.                              public static final String PWD_PATTERN_ALP_UP = "(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*";                                                     public static boolean isAlphabetPresent(String text) {
  
  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(Constants.PWD_PATTERN_ALP_UP, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
  return matcher.find();
  
 }

Comment: Thanks HMK for the details. I am new to android. I did not understand ur last comment. Shoud i be using regex "\\(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*" . It gives me some error. It would be grt if u cud post the modified one for android.